# Not sure what function to use?

Tags: microsoft-excel, dropdownlist

I am trying to make a table to do some easier real estate math.

I am going to have a drop down list for my categories, and a drop down list for my number of bedrooms.

I want Excel to look at the category I choose from the list (yellow row), then look at the bedroom count (orange column), and provide back the intersection point (green cell).

Any ideas on how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Ideas would only be opinions.   Have you asked a Real Estate Professional?

Comment: What you want is known as a [Two-way Lookup](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/two-way-lookup.html); [other ways of the same](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/index-match-match-two-dimensional-lookup-excel/).

Comment: For the given data (equal steps in both directions) you can simply calculate:
`Value = 800 + (CODE(Category) – CODE("A")) * 10 + Number * 10`

Comment: INDEX over all the values as a single range with a MATCH to find the row for the category and then "number"+1 for the column (don't waste a match when looking for an integer in a continuous range of integers)

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(XLOOKUP(D1;C5:C14;C5:C14));COLUMN(XLOOKUP(D2;D4:G4;D4:G4))))
```

Where

- `D1` => Category selection field
- `C5:C14` => Category column (A to Z)
- `D2` => Number selection field
- `D4:G4` => Row with number of rooms (0, 1, 2, ...)

In short: Using the selected values, row and column are extracted via `XLOOKUP`, then the target cell address is created and referenced via `INDIRECT`.
A bit overkill given your quasi-predictable data, but the generic solution.